# 6061 ALUMINUM TUBE (Round)

Tags: drive-shaft

The aluminum tube 6061 is considered as one of the high strength tube.
However, can the round 6061 ALUMINUM TUBE be used in the drive shaft tube?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you are the person who has been asking questions about drive shafts and would like to consolidate the three questions under one account, please [send a note](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to the community moderators and they should be able to combine them.

Comment: See this question : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/53648/10976

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what manufacturers use for their mass produced aluminum drivelines (though they may use it), but aftermarket driveline manufacturers such as [Denny's](http://www.dennysdriveshaft.com/c3_aluminum_6061_t6_driveshafts.html) use 6061-T6 tubing to create their drivelines. Even their yokes are made from forged 6061-T6.  So, to answer your question: **yes, it is a good choice when building drivelines**.

Comment: One possible disadvantage is the rate of corrosion of aluminium compared to other metals... I have seen many of the aircraft engines produced during WW2 suffering massive corrosion - but since they were not worried about an extended life they may have known and ignored that...

Comment: @SolarMike - More than steel? I wouldn't think so. Even with corrosion, it appears the 6061 is the tube of choice for aftermarket drivelines.

Comment: Im thinking Aluminum during WWII is not the same now.

Comment: Then you need to see some of the engines from german dorniers and messerschmitts ... I have at a distance of two feet (some very good displays of stuff dug out of the ground - « bomb alley » is a good source as the Battle of Britain provided plenty of examples that can still be found... Farmers continue to plough up stuff each year) and the rate of corrosion is stunning, while the steel bits used are still relatively fine...

Comment: Corrosion of aluminum would not be a factor in drive-train . I don't doubt it is used  but aluminum sacrifices stiffness and fatigue life compared to steel , to reduce weight,

Comment: @blacksmith37 - would suggest you read Carroll Smith's *Engineer to Win*, if you ever get a chance. He talks about metal fatigue. He also talks about how cylindrical objects (like a drive shaft) suffer in torsion. The diameter of the tube along with the wall thickness have a lot to do with how well a drive line stands up to the stress.

Comment: If interested in metal machinery failures ; Look up Don Wulpis' book - "How components Fail". A classic with many pictures. He was the failure analyst for International Harvester until the company failed - engineering humor. I did metallurgical failure analysis for 40 yr , retired now so no more books for me.Actually , I have about 100 pounds of ASM Metals Handbooks 8th and 9th editions that I could give somebody.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - That's pretty awesome. The only reason why I was suggesting *Engineer to Win* is because it applies directly to motorsports.